# Error with Inner Join query in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hql

I'm trying to execute a Hibernate Query in a JSF Project, but I'm getting this error message:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: agencia of: entity.Conta
```

Here's my query method:

```
public static Conta procurarSenha(String agencia, String conta, String cpf) {
    EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("BANCO");
    EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
    try {
        TypedQuery<Conta> query = em.createQuery("SELECT con from Conta c INNER JOIN c.usuario u ON c.USER_CPF = u.cpf "
                + "WHERE c.agencia = :ag AND c.conta = :ct AND u.cpf = :cp", Conta.class);
        query.setParameter("ag", agencia);
        query.setParameter("ct", conta);
        query.setParameter("cp", cpf);
        List<Conta> contas = query.getResultList();
        em.clear();
        em.close();
        factory.close();
        if (contas != null && contas.size() > 0) {
            return contas.get(0);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Here's the Conta class:

```
@Entity
public class Conta {
@EmbeddedId
private DadosConta contaUsuario = new DadosConta();
private String senha;
private String tipoConta;
private double saldo;
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="USER_CPF", unique= true, nullable=false, insertable=true, 
updatable=true)
private Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
@OneToMany(mappedBy="contaOrigem", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Transacao> transacoes = new ArrayList<>();
... getters and setters
```

Here's the DadosConta (Embedded Id) class:

```
@Embeddable
public class DadosConta {
private String agencia;
private String conta;
...getters and setters
```

And here's the Usuario class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "usuario")
public class Usuario {

private String nome;
private String cpf;
private String rg;
private Date dataNasc;
private String telefone;
private String email;
private String logradouro;
private String numero;
private String cep;
...getters and setters
```

When I query for one of them, without the Inner Join, it works correctly, but when I query for a join between these classes it shows the error message. This query is correct in MySQL, but in Hibernate it's not working. Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: Although the error message indicates something different, this is not SQL but you are using JPQL where `ON` clause is not allowed (There is a different way to formulate the same query).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following query:

```
SELECT con from Conta c INNER JOIN c.usuario u WHERE   
c.contaUsuario.agencia = :ag AND c.conta = :ct AND u.cpf = :cp
```

your CompoundedKey is referenced in a variable name **contaUsuario** so you have to pass through it.

Also as mentioned by tiny you can't use INNER JOIN wih ON as you are writting JPQL not SQL

Comment: Thank you, it worked, I was thinking that's not necessary cause agencia is Composite Key from Conta, but it's another class, and we need to use the class names, not the columns, right? Thank you.

Comment: Exactly, it is JPQL syntax so you have to work with class name and attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the field `agencia` in class `conta`. Instead of querying for `c.agencia` you need to query for `c.contaUsuario.agencia`.